# querySelectorAll text endline deliminers & nextSibling

Tags: javascript, html

When I call `querySelectorAll('#fchildP')` and I want to get it's firstChild node, it returns `#text node` with data property of `\n` resp `"breakline"` and nextSibling is `p` element which is `#fchild`'s child. Code might help to understand:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <p id="fchildP">
        <p>This is first child of #fchildP</p>
        <span id="fchildPchild"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var child = $('#fchildP').child(':first-child'); // returns text endline deliminer
var next = $('#fchildP').next();  // returns p
```

So I call `querySelectorAll('#fchildP').firstChild` => returns: text *with endline deliminer as data* and when I call `querySelectorAll('#fchildP').nextSibling` => returns: *`p node` with "This is first child of #fchildP" as data* and it is child element of `#fchildP`. Why is it happening? And how could I get `firstChild` but element, and not the `text endline deliminer`?

*PS: this is not jQuery, it's my own library*

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a html collection so `querySelectorAll('#fchildP').firstChild` should be undefined

Comment: It’s always useful to inspect an object (HTML element) in the object debugger to see which properties it has.

Comment: firstChild is `text (endline deliminer)` and firstElementChild is null  **I have printed result of `querySelectorAll` in console, so I see all the properties in NodeList**

Comment: Also, make sure not to use the same ID multiple times.

Comment: I am not using the same ID on multiple elements.

Comment: Why are you using `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` or even `getElementById` then?

Comment: @Xufox: Because his `$` function is a wrapper for qSA, much like jQuery's `$`?

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

- You can’t nest `<p>` elements. Nested `<p>` elements will close the parent before opening a new one. Use something else. For example a `<div id="fchildP">`…`</div>`
- Use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild` to get the element rather than the text node
- Pick *the first element* from the `NodeList` returned by `document.querySelectorAll(`…`)` with `[0]`

Comment: `firstElementChild` is empty (`null`) and hashtag `#` is not there (mistake when I wrote code here) it's already edited  **EDIT: I am using `querySelectorAll` because I have a library and I use multiple selectors ... As you can see in code (JS) i call $ object function**

Comment: @Peter You’re using nested `<p>` elements. That’s another issue.

Comment: The main issue in fact. All along the OP has been working with a different DOM than what he thinks he is working with.

Comment: But I've got it .. guys .. if got it handled with `this.first(function (callback)) {});` .. so I AM working with 0th property of my library `Object` so dont worry about that ... I can see in console.log .. so p cant be nested .. and can I nest <div> elements?

Comment: Thanks. And insead `childNodes` I have to use `children` to avoid text nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Paragraph elements can't be nested. When HTML parser sees an opening `<p>` tag, it implicitly closes the previously opened `P` element (since [its closing tag is optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#optional-tags)). So, given your markup, the second `P` becomes not the child of `#fchildP`, but its sibling (and the `#fchildP` itself has no content except the newline character).